# Relation on scope on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here are my ActiveRecord models, with Rails 3.2 :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :criterion
    has_many :user_offer_choices
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_offer_choices

    def seen
        user_offer_choices.where(seen: true)
    end

    def accepted
        user_offer_choices.where(accepted: true)
    end
end

class Criterion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class UserOfferChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :offer
end
```

I want to get all the criterions of the users who have seen an offer. Something like :

```
Offer.find(11).seen.users.criterions
```

but I do not know how to to it with ActiveRecord

I know I can do something like :

```
Criterion.joins(user: { user_offer_choices: :offer }).where(user: { user_offer_choices: {accepted: true, offer_id: 11}  } )
```

But I want to be able to use my scopes on offers (seen & accepted). So how can I do it ?

*Edit :*
I have found what I was looking for, the merge method of Arel : http://benhoskin.gs/2012/07/04/arel-merge-a-hidden-gem

Answer (score 4):

First, what you really want is define a scope on your choices.

```
class UserOfferChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :offer

  scope :seen, where(seen: true)
  scope :accepted, where(accepted: true)
end
```

Which allows you to do this

```
Offer.find(11).user_offer_choices.seen
```

and to get the criteria:

```
Offer.find(1).user_offer_choices.seen.map{|choice| choice.user}.map{|user| user.criterion}
```

Now, this could be cleaned up with a has many through in the Offer class.

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_offer_choices
  has_many :users, :through => :user_offer_choices
end
```

but that gets us to the user, but skipping the scope.

```
Offer.find(1).users
```

Now, there's a trick you can do with Rails 3 scopes which you could not do with Rails 2.3.5 named_scopes.  The named_scopes took a hash as arguments but returned a relation.  The Rails 3 scopes take a relation, as from query methods like where.  So you can define a scope in users, *using the scope defined in your choices class*!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :criterion
  has_many :user_offer_choices
  has_many :offers, :through => :user_offer_choices

  scope :seen, UserOfferChoice.seen
  scope :accepted, UserOfferChoice.accepted
end
```

That allows us to do this:

```
Offer.find(1).users.seen
```

The map now looks like this:

```
Offer.find(1).users.seen.map{|user| user.criterion}
```

BTW, the plural of criterion is criteria.  Hearing criterions in my head when I read it, hurts.  You can do this to get Rails to know the plural:

```
config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^criterion$/i, 'criteria'
end
```

Comment: I do not want to use map (or other Enum method), because it's plain Ruby and ActiveRecord won't generate SQL.

Comment: Why is it important to use SQL instead of map?  That seems to me to be an arbitrary contrived requirement.  If you notice, I demonstrated how to go from nesting two map calls, (which is cumbersome and hard to read) to a solution which gets rid of one map and uses SQL and your scopes.  You might try extending that technique, but I think then that solution will be cumbersome.  (More about map vs SQL in next comment.)

Comment: Using map does have a downside that it loops through the collection, but then makes a call to the database in the loop to dereference the association.  When I changed the choice map to the has-many-through it made one SQL call for the given Offer object, and built the join for us.  However, I wouldn't worry about performance until we determined that the whole web response took too long.

Comment: I agree with you. But why use a map on the collection, when it is dead simple to get all the objects with only one (simple) SQL statement ?

Comment: I agree.  When SQL can get the right results, it can be more efficient to just get the results.  I post a lot of SQL centric answers, where I show the SQL which gets the right results and then translate them into query methods (or find arguments).  The thing is, I have done a lot of work on this, (because I wanted to show off calling a scope from another class), starting with code that did not get the right result, and did not define scopes in a way that showed you looked up scopes.  I think you could do some effort taking it the rest of the way.  (Look at other answers of mine.)

Comment: I've tried your solution. It works, but there is only one downside. You defined scopes on User, but they are not working only with a User (like User.accepted). ActiveRecord misses the implicit joins from the relations and generates a SQL statement without join : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "user_offer_choices"."accepted" = 't'

Comment: I know what's going on.  I actually set up a project like yours and tested the code examples I gave.  So I know Offer.find(1).users.seen works.  It works because ActiveRecord adds the join from the users association.  However, just using the Users::seen scope alone, would be missing the join.  Just add the joins method, for a User.joins(:offers).seen expression.  This will also help getting rid of the second map, User.joins(:user_offer_choices, :criterion).seen.where("user_offer_choices.offer_id = :offer_id", :offer_id => 11).select("criteria.*")